# Laravel scheduler not running artisan command

Tags: laravel, scheduler, laravel-forge

I wrote a custom artisan command ("get App's Metrics") and added it to the Kernel on my Forge-hosted site to used Laravel's awesome scheduler feature to run it every night.

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\GetAppsMetricsForDay::class
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('get:metrics')->daily();
    }
```

Except it doesn't run every night.  I can run it on the command line - the command is good.  There are no errors in Forge's log file.  What's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

On Forge, you need to "go back up one level" from you site's control panel to your server's control panel, and create the schedule:run command that will run any commands you add to your application

[image]